# Base SAS Certification with an input keyword inside an if statement

Tags: sas

I had a question regarding the Base SAS exam.
This question appeared on one of the practice tests.

The question asks how many records will be input from the following data

```
A 1995 100
B 1997 200
C 1996 200
D 1994 200
E 1997 200
F 1992 200
```

The code in the question was as written below

```
data one;
    infile rawdata;
    input @3 year 4.;
        if year = 1997 then input @8 amount 3.;
run;
```

The correct answer is 4 records. But I don't see how this works.
Could someone help me with a detailed explanation of what goes on inside the PDV.

I thought that only two observations will be read.

How is the first line of this file processed.
When the first line is read shouldn't only the value of year be read.
In the second line, the data reads both year and amount.
This is confusing.

Let me know where am I going wrong

Comment: Add some `PUT` statements to see what it happening.  You can use `PUT _INFILE_;` to see the current line that was just read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate Joe's point about the input values for `amount` coming from the following line, try running the following:

```
data one;
  input @3 year 4.;
  if year = 1997 then input @8 amount 3.;
  cards;
A 1995 100
B 1997 200
C 1996 300
D 1994 200
E 1997 200
F 1992 300
;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a trick question.  That's because the behavior described by the code is, probably, wrong.  (That's what they're testing you to see - if you can spot the error, basically.)

Nothing in that code tells SAS not to output a line, whether or not a particular value is present.  The `if year=1997` bit doesn't have an `output` in it, so every line is output including the other lines.

However, the first `input` doesn't have an `@` telling it to hold the line pointer!  That means that, rather than inputting the `amount` associated with that `year` record, it will actually input the *next* `amount` field.

So you'll have the following lines:

```
A 1995
B 1997 200 <- but the 200 from C!
D 1994
E 1997 200 <- but the 200 from F!
```

I would recommend debugging the code with the data step debugger to see more clearly.

Here's a PUT-based debug that can help you see a bit better:

```
data one;
    infile datalines;
    input @3 year 4.;
    infile_var = _INFILE_;
    put "After first readin" +1 year= +1 "_INFILE_="  infile_var;
    if year = 1997 then input @8 amount 3.;
    infile_var = _INFILE_;
    put "After IF statement" +1 year = +1 "_INFILE_="  infile_var /;
    datalines;
A 1995 100
B 1997 200
C 1996 200
D 1994 200
E 1997 200
F 1992 200
;;;;
run;
```

Log contents afterwards:

```
After first readin year=1995  _INFILE_=A 1995 100
After IF statement year=1995  _INFILE_=A 1995 100

After first readin year=1997  _INFILE_=B 1997 200
After IF statement year=1997  _INFILE_=C 1996 200

After first readin year=1994  _INFILE_=D 1994 200
After IF statement year=1994  _INFILE_=D 1994 200

After first readin year=1997  _INFILE_=E 1997 200
After IF statement year=1997  _INFILE_=F 1992 200
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 30 seconds. This sort of thing is absolutely typical of certification questions.

Comment: Hey I just had my certification exam today. I passed. They asked

Comment: They asked a similar question

Comment: Congrats! @AjayKumar